# How can I parse this JSON response

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing, arraylist, response

I have the following JSON data being received by angularJS. It's being brought in from an ArrayList using a get request.

```
    0: Object
        id:1
        area: "State"
        gender: "Both"
        highestEd: 3608662
        .... etc

    1: Object
        id:2
        area: "State"
        gender: "Both"
        highestEd: 3608662
        .... etc
```

However I can't figure out how to access it using either a controller or the UI. I want to be able to store this data in Angular so I can then create graphs using the information. The only way I know it's definitely there is through looking at the response in firefox.

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the data using $http? Where are you getting the data from? Service or Controller? And if possible please share some code as to what you have already tried.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the data through a http get request in the factory. I'm trying to store it in a scope variable before processing it. 

In terms of trying to process the variables, I've tried ng-repeats nested and not nested. I'm currently working off a JSfiddle and it parses here but not in my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/2493/

Comment: Can you share your factory and controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your JSON data is not in proper format. Use [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com) to check
2. Use `$http.get('/get_url/')` to get the response . [One sample example for this](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_http_get).
3. Once you have response in `$scope.yourVariable` use `ng-repeat` to loop over it

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just changed my controller to one the exact same in the example you linked. Thanks a million

Comment: @user3456450: its the beauty of SO. Please mark this as answer to help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2d11vypm/) you might get some ideas.

After calling the API using $http from you factory you will have resolve the data that you are getting. The controller needs to call the API method and then bind the resolved data from your factory to the API.

**Factory**

```
myApp.factory("Data", function($q, $http) {
  return {
    getData: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      /* --Actual API Call
            $http.get("/url")
        .then(function(response) {
          deferred.resolve(response.data);
        })
                */
                //Dummy Data
      var data = m;
      deferred.resolve(data);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope, Data) {
  Data.getData()
    .then(function(items) {
      $scope.bobs = items;
      console.log($scope.bobs);
    })
}
```

Replace the dummy data initialization from factory to the actual API call.